# 3-way multiplexer built on 2-way multiplexers in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I created [this project on EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Vfme) that builds a variable-width 3-way multiplexer out of 2 variable-width 2-way multiplexers. It will be part of homework that I assign, so I want to follow all best practices. I followed the [lowRISC Verilog Coding Style Guide](https://github.com/lowRISC/style-guides/blob/master/VerilogCodingStyle.md).

**Design Modules**

```
module mux2 #(
  parameter Width = 4
) (
  input              control,
  input [Width-1:0]  a,
  input [Width-1:0]  b,
  output [Width-1:0] y
);
  
  assign y = control ? b : a;
  
endmodule

module mux3 #(
  parameter Width = 4
) (
  input [1:0]        control,
  input [Width-1:0]  a,
  input [Width-1:0]  b,
  input [Width-1:0]  c,
  output [Width-1:0] y
);
  
  wire [Width-1:0] mux_a_out;
  
  mux2 #(
    .Width   (Width)
  ) mux_a (
    .control (control[0]), 
    .a       (a), 
    .b       (b), 
    .y       (mux_a_out)
  );
  
  mux2 #(
    .Width   (Width)
  ) mux_b (
    .control (control[1]), 
    .a       (mux_a_out), 
    .b       (c), 
    .y       (y)
  );
  
endmodule
```

**Test Module**

```
module test;
  reg[1:0] control;
  reg[7:0] a;
  reg[7:0] b;
  reg[7:0] c;
  reg[7:0] y;
  
  mux3 #(
    .Width(8)
  ) mux3(
    .control (control),
    .a       (a),
    .b       (b),
    .c       (c),
    .y       (y)
  );
  
  initial begin
    a = "A";
    b = "B";
    c = "C";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      begin
        control = i;
        #1
        $display("When Control = %d, Y = %c", control, y);
      end
  end
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems with the code functionally, and the layout follows good practices for the most part.  That style guide seems mostly reasonable, and it is a good idea to use a set of guidelines.

In my many years of Verilog coding, I have most frequently seen parameters use all capital letters (this departs from the guide you posted):

Use `WIDTH` instead of `Width`.

The guide recommends 2-space indents in some places and 4 in others; I recommend **4-space** indent everywhere because I think it is much easier to read.

I don't think  your `for` loop follows the guide.  I would lay it out like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) begin
    control = i;
    #1
    $display("When Control = %d, Y = %c", control, y);
end
```

I would also add a space between `reg` and `[`:

```
  reg [1:0] control;
  reg [7:0] a;
  reg [7:0] b;
  reg [7:0] c;
  reg [7:0] y;
```

I usually find it helpful for debugging to also display the time (copied from my Answer to your previous Verilog Question):

```
$display($time, " When Control = %d, Y = %c", control, y);
```

The `for` loop exercises 3 of the 4 possible values of `Control`.  It is a good practice to simulate all possibilities (`Control` = 3).  Perhaps make it an extra-credit question to explain what happens and why.

---

I assume one of the goals of this assignment is to demonstrate module hierarchy using an extremely simple design.  Otherwise, your design modules normally would be replaced with a single `assign` statement.

Comment: Thank you! Your feedback is helpful, and your assumption is correct.